# Как временно отменить несколько коммитов из master?

Tags: git

История коммитов

`A -> B -> C -> D -> E`

Выяснилось, что `В` и `D` содержат баг. Надо убрать эти изменения из `master`. Но скорей всего, потом их можно будет вернуть с ещё одним коммитом-фиксом. Как лучше сделать?

Comment: revert commit (это сохранит коммиты, но отменит новым коммитом, который позже можно будет разотменить), либо сделать отдельную ветку (1) начиная с A, потом начиная с D сделать ребейз на ветку (1) и ветка будет без коммитов B, C , но в таком случае потеряются коммиты.

Comment: @SultanovShamil на мой взгляд, это полноценный ответ. Оформите его ответом.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать Revert commit. Он создаст новый коммит, который будет обратным для отменяемого, таким образом в истории коммиты сохранятся. При необходимости вернуть изменения, можно будет отменить отмену т.е. сделать Revert Commit для того коммита, который отменяет изменения :)
2. Сделать отдельную ветку (newBranch) начиная с A, потом начиная с D сделать Rebase на ветку (newBranch). Таким образом newBranch будет без коммитов B, C , но в таком случае потеряются коммиты из истории.